# What event to use for successful order creation

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, development

I need to run some custom code after a successful order creation. I'll need to access each item in an order, both the quote item and subsequent order item. My first instinct was to use the following events:

- sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item
- sales_order_item_save_after

However, when using the Authorize.net gateway, both of these events are dispatched when a transaction fails and no order is created! Is there a later event to use that would still allow access to quote items? Or, is there a way to test for a successful transaction within these two events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `checkout_submit_all_after`.

Answer (score 0):

I've used sales_order_item_save_after and then checked for a pending status on the order like so:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
if($order->getStatus()=="processing"){
    //Your observer code
}
```

Then make sure that your authorize.net payment method is configured to set new orders to the processing status. This also works well for other payment methods like Purchase Orders.